# Calculate day of the week based on user input

Tags: java, swing, calendar

I'm having trouble figuring out how make my program calculate the day of the week based on user input for month, day, year. Such as in this picture below. I have no clue on how to make it connect with the JTextField and the JComboBoxes. I truly appreciate anyones help with this. I know is I'm supposed to use:

Calendar xmas = new GregorianCalendar(1998, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
int dayOfWeek = xmas.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // 6=Friday

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;



public class DayOfWeek extends JFrame 
{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField yearField;
    private JLabel dayOfW;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    DayOfWeek frame = new DayOfWeek();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DayOfWeek()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 230);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel monthL = new JLabel("Month:");
        monthL.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(monthL);

        JComboBox monthBox = new JComboBox();
        monthBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}));
        monthBox.setBounds(53, 8, 109, 20);
        contentPane.add(monthBox);

        JLabel dayL = new JLabel("Day: ");
        dayL.setBounds(172, 11, 31, 14);
        contentPane.add(dayL);

        JComboBox dayBox = new JComboBox();
        dayBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"}));
        dayBox.setBounds(203, 8, 53, 20);
        contentPane.add(dayBox);

        JLabel yearL = new JLabel("Year: ");
        yearL.setBounds(266, 11, 37, 14);
        contentPane.add(yearL);

        yearField = new JTextField();
        yearField.setBounds(301, 8, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(yearField);
        yearField.setColumns(10);



        JLabel dayOfW;
        dayOfW = new JLabel("The day of the week is");
        dayOfW.setBounds(10, 153, 126, 14);
        contentPane.add(dayOfW);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(172, 148, 160, 19);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        Calendar xmas = new GregorianCalendar(1998, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
        int dayOfWeek = xmas.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // 6=Friday




    yearField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Why don't you create a button? Then you set an action to that button, and you check day it is, according to the input fields. 
Otherwise, you would have to do it on change events in the three fields, i guess.

Comment: Just get values from input, pass them to Gregorian Calendar constructor, get from calendar day of the week and print it to label..

Comment: I can't create a button for it, it can only be calculated through pressing enter of the yearField. So I don't really know how to link that.

Comment: @user2268587 Ok, that's something you should have said on the initial post. Please, check my answer.

Comment: please fix the question title.

Answer (score 2):

You have any number of options...

### You Could

Use a `FocusListener` on each field and when `focusLost` is called, validate the state of each field to determine if you have enough information to perform the required calculations...but this doesn't take into account what might happen if the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the last field...

### You Could

Use an `ActionListener` on each field to detect when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or the individual fields are actioned) and validate the state of each field to determine if you have enough information to perform the required calculations, but this doesn't take into account the case where the user doesn't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the field

### You Could

Do both, use a `FocusListener` and `ActionListener` which simply calls a method that validates the state of each field to determine if you have enough information to perform the required calculations

### You Could

Have a `JButton` that the user is required to press in order to perform the calculations.  When activated it would validate the state of each field to determine if you have enough information to perform the required calculations

Take a look at:

- [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Write a Focus Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

You could even use an `InputVerifier`, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details

Now, having said all that, you're main problem is a reference issue.

All you fields are declared locally to the constructor.  While you could declare them as `final` and you'd be able to access them from within the inner class of the `ActionListener`, personally, I would declare them as instance variables, so that you could access them from anywhere within the class itself.  This provides you with a greater opportunity to implement the logic as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use awt listener on swing component. swing comes out with DocumentListener which will listen for field text change.

```
yearField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  calc();
}
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  calc();
}
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  calc();
}

public void calc() {
   //get values from fields
   //pass them to gregorian calendar constructor
   //get day of week from calendar
   //print day to label
}
});
```

Comment: *"Dont use awt listener on swing component"* - Why? It's directly supported by the API ([`JTextField#addActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yearField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        //check the value of the other input fields
        //do the calculations

        textArea.setText("the result here");    
    }

});
```

Comment: No, never, nutta.  You should never add a `KeyListener` to a text component.  In the use case you've presented, this is what an `ActionListener` would be used for.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, didn't know that. Just realized now that the ActionListener is triggered when you press the Enter key and the focus is in the field, what is the same I was doing, theoretically. Edited my answer.